# If x is a real number, what is the smallest possible value of x sq + 8?

Tags: quadratics

[image: Question and Solution Both Here]

In the solution in the above link, how did they assume x sq to be zero. If x sq is a real no then why couldn't they take is as some -ve number as it is less than 0?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is a increasing function which only takes real $x$.

Comment: @Fightclub1995. It seems that the question is about $x^2+8$

Comment: You're welcome to try finding real numnbers $x$ where $x^2$ is less than $0$. Try a negative number and see what happens. Trial and error is an important way to learn mathematics (and sadly underrated in our school system, where errors are often seen as fails, and students are afraid to attempt anything because making mistakes is somehow wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say $x = -1,$

then $(-1)^2 + 8 \\=1+8 \\=9$

which is greater than if $x = 0$

this is because $(-1) \times (-1) = 1$

Comment: Thank You! Understood. :)

Answer (score 0):

By x sq you mean $x^2$ ?

If $x \in \mathbb R$, then $x^2 \ge 0$, hence $x^2+8 \ge 8$.

Conclusion: $8 \le x^2+8$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

For $x=0$ we have $8 =x^2+8$. Hence

$ \min\{x^2+8: x \in \mathbb R\}=8$